# Acces wso2 GReg resources to build ws clients with cxf

Tags: maven, wsdl, wso2, cxf, wsdl2java

I was wondering if you can access remotely to the wsdls stored on the wso2 SOA Governance registry and use that wsdls to create ws client using apache cxf with maven.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the WSDL's stored in the registry just like any other artifact stored in the registry. But crating ws clients using Apache cxf with maven is something you do after you get the WSDL if i understand correctly. The following samples [1] provides how to search services that are stored in the registry. But you as given in step 3 in the sample you can use "wsdl" instead of "service" to get the wsdl's.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance460/Governance+Artifact+Search+Sample